# Enabling 2 legged OAuth2.0

Tags: linkedin-api

We are trying to call LinkedIn API from our applications. Hence could you please enable OAuth2.0 client_credentials flow (i.e 2 legged Oauth2.0) our App "Oracle CX Test"

We are trying to consume LinkedIn API from our applications. Hence could you please enable OAuth2.0 client_credentials flow (i.e 2 legged Oauth2.0) our App "Oracle CX Test"